Getting "Site May be Malicious" For a Phantom Wallet Transaction method I'm trying to create
I'm trying to create a method where users must send a specific spl-token in exchange for a service. I created the code, but I get a warning from blowfish saying the site may be malicious. I emailed review@blowfish.xyz, but they said they wanted a refferal from someone well known in the solana-dev-community, but since I'm new to the crypto community, I don't know anyone. Can anyone help me, or let me know what I should do? Thanks!

did you solve this?
